# Timeout with MassTransit IRequestClient

Tags: c#, .net, masstransit

```
public class CarCreatedConsumer: IConsumer<CarCreatedEvent>
{
   private readonly IMediator _mediator;
   public CarCreatedConsumer(IMediator mediator)
   {
        _mediator = mediator;
   }
   public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<CarCreatedEvent> context)
   {
      var command = new SendEmailCommand(context.Message.Details);
      bool success = await _mediator.Send(command);
      if(!success)
      { 
         return new Exception("There was an error!")
      }
   }
}
```

`SendEmailCommandHandler` in debug successfully receives command and handles it with mocked repositories (I'm hiding this details cause I think its irrelevant to this question) but still I'm getting `TimeOutException` in `client.GetResponse<CarCreatedEvent>` when testing.

Here's how I setup test following [masstransit unit test consumer docs](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/testing.html#consumer)

```
public class MyTests
{
  private ITestHarness _harness;
  private ServiceProvider _provider;

  [SetUp]
  public void SetUp()
  {
   _provider = new ServiceCollection()
        .AddMassTransitTestHarness(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddConsumer<CarCreatedConsumer>();
            cfg.AddHandler<SendEmailCommand>(context => context.RespondAsync(true));
        })
        .AddMediatR(options =>
        {
            options.AsTransient();
        }, Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(CarCreatedConsumer)))
        .BuildServiceProvider(true);

    _harness = _provider.GetRequiredService<ITestHarness>();
}

[Test]
public async Task ShouldRespond()
{
    await _harness.Start();
    var client = _harness.GetRequestClient<CarCreatedEvent>();
    try
    {
        await client.GetResponse<CarCreatedEvent>(new
        {
            Id = 1,
            CarOwnerName = "John"
        });
    }catch (Exception e)
    { 
        **// Getting TimeoutException here!**
        throw;
    }
  
    Assert.IsTrue(await _harness.Sent.Any<CarCreatedEvent>());
    Assert.IsTrue(await _harness.Consumed.Any<CarCreatedEvent>());
    var consumerHarness = _harness.GetConsumerHarness<CarCreatedEventHandler>();

    Assert.That(await consumerHarness.Consumed.Any<CarCreatedEvent>());
}
```

Again, when I run the test I was able to hit consumer and from there to create command which is successfully handled by its handler and saved into mocked repository, but I am unable to hit Assert lines cause I'm getting TimeoutException.

Answer (score 1):

Your consumer didn't respond, which is why it times out. Your consumer should call `context.RespondAsync` with a response message for the request client.

This is all covered [in the documentation](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/requests.html).